# Starting an app and cmd without focusing on their windows

Tags: windows, focus, autohotkey

The current situation is that I have a mouse button binding in AutoHotkey to kill a process, do some file operations and then start an application (.exe).

I would like to start the app without losing the focus of the current fullscreen window I am using.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us te code that you have already tried so far. Also, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get better answers.

Comment: Why use a batch file if you can `Run` the exe directly from AHK?

Comment: Because the batch file turns off an app, looks for a string in the apps' ini file and replaces that file if it finds the string. It just starts that app after these.

Comment: You can do all that with AHK.

Comment: Ok, now Ive added the things that I was doing in that bat file previously to the AHK script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the window (Mainwindow) that you want to keep the focus on to be always on top. Note that this doesnt work with a fullscreen app (I couldn't find a solution for a true fullscreen app), but it works fine with a windowed one:
   [Winset](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm), Alwaysontop, , Mainwindow
2. Run the side app and wait until it creates a window:
   Run, Sideapp.exe, , hide;
   [WinWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm), Sideapp
3. Focus on the main window again:
   WinActivate, Mainwindow

Thank you for everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

In Autohotkey you have the function `WinActivate` to give the focus on a windows :

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm

Comment: +1 This allows the batch and program to launch and take focus, but you can immediately return focus to your application.

Comment: with adding a sleep 175-200 I could make it working this way
but it takes too much time for the the OS to refocus on that fullscreen program that I use.
It would be better if the bat and app dont take the focus at all.

Comment: I have tried to use "Run, my.exe, , hide" and "min" but those didn't seem to affect the window's size.

Comment: Its quite dependent on how fast that app can start up. With the same sleep-time Sometimes it doesnt drop out of fullscreen sometimes it does.

Comment: @polarka Which app are we talking about? Your best chance is that it provides a command line switch for not activating its window on start.

Comment: Its a standalone .exe and its readme didn't contain any technical details. Probably it doesnt contain such an option because that wouldnt be useful for its intended usage. If you insist, i can link the file or just start pming the guy who made it.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways to accomplish this, assuming there are no command line switches to start it minimized or hidden.

1. [FileCreateShortcut](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileCreateShortcut.htm) allows  a `RunState` parameter.  You could create a shortcut with a RunState of minimized, then execute the shortcut. The effectiveness of this depends largely on what type of application it is.
2. Use [WinWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) with a timeout period to wait for your executed program to exist, then use `WinActivate` to reactivate your fullscreen  application.  This will allow your application start time to vary, and you will not have to hard code sleep times.

Comment: Maybe, setting the fullscreen window always on top could resolve the issue, too.

Comment: Always on top doesnt work in fullscreen. However I have just tried it in windowed fullscreen and it works there, so the problem I asked/proposed is solved this way, thanks. My current problem is that the way how I do it, that is restarting the exe with new ini settings is too slow, I should rather adjust the settings of it while its running. But thats a different topic ill ask soon, because I dont have an idea how to approach it.

Comment: Another problem you may be able to help with here is that I installed [this always-on-top.exe](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/149566/Downloads/always-on-top.zip) some time ago which works. But I want to get rid of it now that I am more familiar with AHK, because I just want to use that single line in my script. The problem is that always-on-top.exe doesnt run any process, I couldn't find the file itself nor in the registry. So I just don't know how and why it still works every time I start my pc.

Comment: meawhile I have solved the always-on-top.exe problem